# Ajax call not returning correct variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

I'm having an issue with getting this ajax function to work, not sure where i'm messing up.

```
var getTotalEntries = function(query) {
  var total;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: query,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.total);
      total = data.total;
    }
  });

  return total;     
};
```

this logs 65 to the console, but returns undefined... not sure what is going on.

Comment: The *A* in Ajax stands for **asynchronous**. If you could just `return` the value from that function, why would you have to pass a `success` *callback*?

Answer (score 5):

The ajax call and your return statement are asynchronous, not synchronous, so your return statement is firing before the ajax call returns and sets the variable.

One way to handle this issue is to perform whatever actions you want to perform with the data inside the success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: query,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.total);
      total = data.total;

      // do stuff with total here, or invoke function that uses total
      doSomething(total);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous. So the execution continues without waiting for the return value. You could do something like this:

```
var getTotalEntries = function(query) {
  var total;      
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: query,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.total);
      total = data.total;

      //pass the total value here
      processReturn(total);
    },
    //you may want to add a error block
    error: function(e, xhr, settings, exception){

    }
  });

  return total;     
};
```

Code the handling method to process the total:

```
var processReturn = function(total) {
   //use the total value here    
   console.log(total);
};
```

That should take care of it.